# Hover highlight child should not highlight parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to highlight the element when I hover over it (adding class). I have nested elements on my page. What I want is, if i hover over the element, the immediate element gets highlighted not all the parent ones.

Here is the snippet

```
        $("body *").hover(function (e)
        {
            $(this).addClass('test');
        }, function ()
        {
            $(this).removeClass('test');
        });`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZGQr/1/

Comment: Provide specific information quickly before you get downvoted.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZGQr/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("body").mouseover(function (e){
        $(e.target).addClass('test');
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        $(e.target).removeClass('test');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fCfUN/)